# Take off pads with OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, pad

I have to translate from Matlab to C this code:

```
   % take off the pads
   x = (1 + padSize) : (rows - pad8Size);
   y = (1 + padSize) : (cols - padSize);
   rpad=rpad(x,y);
```

1st and 2nd create 2 array, but I don t know how I have to delete it from rpad Mat object It can be something like(subtract every element)

```
    for(int i=1+pad;i<=rows-pad;i++){
     for(int j=1+pad;i<=cols-pad;j++){
            subtract(rpad,x,rpad);
           subtract(rpad,y,rpad);}}
```

Or something like(delete the external element)

```
      int a=(rows-pad)-(1+pad);
      int b=(cols-pad)-(1+pad);
      rpad.create(img.rows - a,img.cols - b,original.type());
      img.copyTo(rpad);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
cv::Rect roi(padSize, padSize, rpad.cols-2*padSize, rpad.rows-2*padSize);
cv::Mat result = rpad(roi);
```

And depending on whether you want continuous memory, you can choose to directly use result (discontinuous, usually okay for most OpenCV functions) or copy it to back to rpad (continuous)

Comment: sorry error commenting... Is it not before rows and after cols?

Comment: er, sorry I don't quite get your question, what do mean by "before rows and after cols"?

Comment: I answer below to explain better

Comment: Rect roi(padSize,padSize,rpad.rows-(2*k),rpad.cols-(2*k));

Comment: but really I have an error in this line: invalid conversion from 'int*' to 'int' because I passed the padSize as *padSize in the function where I use it. But after I pass to k=*padSize;

Comment: Personally I wouldn't pass padSize as int*, but if you did, you can do int k=*padSize; Rect roi(k, k, rpad.rows-2*k, rpad.cols-2*k);

Comment: I give you other question for openCV below

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to multiply a Mat object with a bidimensional array? Imfft is obviously the Mat object

```
      for (int i = 0; i &lt; rows; i++){
         for (int j = 0; j &lt; cols; j++){
               imfft=imfft*filter[i][j]
         }
       }
```

Comment: are u trying to do convolution? And I would suggest you create a new question since this one seems totally different from the previous one.

Comment: I m sorry but I don' t know convolution what means in english in maths. What i m doing is to realize this operation of matlab : imfft=imfft.*filter;  but in my function filter is a bidimensional array